# Android lollipop - Hamburger doesn't animate in spite of setting spinBars to true

Tags: android

Here's my styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/sunshine_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/sunshine_dark_blue</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <!-- Remove the default action bar -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Code for setting the drawer toggle:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("sometitle");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    mToggle.syncState();
```

Now many posts on SO mention that this is the crucial part. But even though I implemented it the hamburger icon on the toolbar doesn't animate. Just so you know the entire implementation of my navigation drawer works perfectly, it's just that the icon doesn't animate...

Comment: Are you using the correct style?

Comment: If this is a specific style, you need to set the style for the view

Comment: That is the general app theme..

Comment: If this is the whole application's theme, make sure you change it in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: The manifest already points to the correct app theme.. which is "AppTheme"

Comment: What is code for setting drawer toggle?

Comment: Hey @Harry, check the latest edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add code as given below,

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

and after oncreate method,

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

No need to apply any style on toggle, this code will solve the purpose.
Hope It will help.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get the hamburger / arrow animation to work with the newer androidx support lib.  I tried all the Toolbar.set*, ActionBar.set*, and ActionBarDrawerToggle.set* functions. In the end, it came down to just needing to call DrawerLayout.addDrawerListener (setDrawerListener is now deprecated) to wire up the drawer sliding progress to the drawer toggle button. Seems like the ActionBarDrawerToggle constructor should have done this since everything needed is passed to it.